# Netlify deploy error for @11ty blog as public does not exist

Tags: netlify, eleventy

I follow the youtube tutorial and build a blog with @11ty.
I want to deploy this blog to Netlify

I connect Netlify to my github public repo for the [source code](https://github.com/raminhafezi/11ty-blog)

I can run this blog locally.
When I deploy the website to Netlif I faced an error during deployment as **" public does not exist "**

```
6:15:32 PM: $ npm run build
6:15:33 PM: > 11ty-blog@1.0.0 build
6:15:33 PM: > eleventy
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/index.html from ./src/blog.njk
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /contact-us/index.html from ./src/contact-us.njk
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /index.html from ./src/index.njk
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/2021-05-01-my-first-article/index.html from ./src/blog/2021-05-01-my-first-article.md (liquid)
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/2021-05-15-my-second-article/index.html from ./src/blog/2021-05-15-my-second-article.md (liquid)
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/2021-05-28-my-third-article/index.html from ./src/blog/2021-05-28-my-third-article.md (liquid)
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/2021-06-15-my-fifth-article/index.html from ./src/blog/2021-06-15-my-fifth-article.md (liquid)
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Writing public /blog/2021-06-01-my-fourth-article/index.html from ./src/blog/2021-06-01-my-fourth-article.md (liquid)
6:15:33 PM: [11ty] Copied 7 files / Wrote 8 files in 0.11 seconds (v2.0.1)
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:33 PM: (build.command completed in 611ms)
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:35 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
6:15:35 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
6:15:35 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
6:15:35 PM: Finished processing build request in 13.223s
6:15:33 PM: Deploy site                                                   
6:15:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:33 PM: Section completed: deploying
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:33 PM: Configuration error                                           
6:15:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:33 PM:   Error message
6:15:33 PM:   Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'public' does not exist
6:15:33 PM: ​
6:15:33 PM:   Resolved config
6:15:33 PM:   build:
6:15:33 PM:     command: npm run build
6:15:33 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
6:15:33 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
6:15:33 PM:     publishOrigin: UI
```

Can not see why it said public does not exist.
On .eleventy.js my output dir is "public" and it is working fine on my local machine.

Thanks